# OSGI/SPRING - Adding non-source folder to runtime environment

Tags: java, spring, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I am running a bundle based project (in eclipse rcp) . In a specific bundle I require access to a folder due to jar-based library code. So in practice my requirement is to have a specific folder with configuration files in my project. If i test my project  as a normal java application everything runs smoothly, however when i try to run it inside osgi it fails since it does not find the folder. How can i add the folder to the runtime environment? I tried to added to the Runtime-Classpath Configuration of the bundle, but this does not solves my problem.

My bundle Manifest. I am trying to add the config/ folder.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: net.beaconcontroller.datastore
Bundle-SymbolicName: net.beaconcontroller.datastore
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Export-Package: net.beaconcontroller.datastore
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 lib/bft-smart-hashserver.jar,
 config/
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your manifest editor, select build and check the folder in the binary build view so that it will be included when you export the plugin.

Then most likely you are not going about loading a bundle/plugin resource correctly which needs be done differently than a regular java application. Here is a code example, give it a try and let me know if it works.

```
public static String loadResourceAsString(String pluginId,
        String resourcePath) throws IOException {
    Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(pluginId);
    URL url = bundle.getResource(resourcePath);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            url.openStream()));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(inputLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    in.close();
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Take a look at what I added in my answer and copy/paste that method to load a resource in the folder. The path should be for example if you have a folder called resources in the root of your plugin and a file in that folder resource1.txt would be "resources/resource1.txt"

Comment: Well, will do, but the thing is that the resource is read by the jar code. I can not modify the code, it will try to read foo("./resource/resource1.txt"). And it fails when it does so. However, I in my bundle can not do it. There most be something wrong in my perception of what is going on.

Comment: this may sound very stupid. But is it possible that it was not working  since the "resource" folder was named config? I see that in the current directory of a bundle there is a config folder with or without  I exporting my config "resource"

Comment: If the resource is read by jar code, you might have a problem. DO you know how it tries to load the config like is it doing Class.getResourceAsStream() how does it know the file path to your bundle if its external jar code?